# Find an item of a list with getname()

Tags: c#, list

Hi yall im trying to get the name of a list. The user input that list. I tried to get a name using 2 methods but it wont let me:

this is the error that im having: `Argument 1: cannot convert from "String" to "ElMaestro.Usuario"`

the list: `private List<Usuario> list = new List<Usuario>();`

This is how i am coding the mehtods:

From class AgregarUsuario

```
  private int EncontrarItem(String buscarItem)
        {

            return list.IndexOf(buscarItem); // Where i am getting the error
   
        }

        public Boolean onFile(String buscarItem)
        {
            int pos = EncontrarItem(buscarItem);
            if(pos >= 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and this is the class Usuario so i can get the name by using getName()

```
namespace ElMaestro
{
    internal class Usuario
    {
        private String name { get; set; }
        private int score { get; set; }
        private String course { get; set; }

        public Usuario(String name, int score, String course)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.score = score;
            this.course = course;
        }

        public String getName() => name;

        public override string ToString() => "\n Nombre del usuario: " + name + "\n Puntaje del curso: " + score + "\n Estado del curso: " + course;
    }
    
}
```

I alsoo tried with lambda expression but didnt work.

Comment: You mean something like `return list.FindIndex((u)=>u.getName() == buscarItem);` -- Not clear why those Properties are `private` -- `getName()` should be `GetName()`, but you probably don't need that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
private int EncontrarItem(String buscarItem)
{
    return list.IndexOf(buscarItem); // Where i am getting the error
}
```

will fail because you have to match the `T` type parameter, [check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-indexof(-0))

Since this is a `List<Usuario>` you need to search with `list.IndexOf(usuarioObj)`

To do this, couple it with LINQ

```cs
private int EncontrarItem(string buscarItem)
{
    Usuario? find = list
        .Where(item => string.Equals(buscarItem, item.name, StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return find != null
        ? list.IndexOf(find)
        : -1; //or throw an exception
}
```

Notice use of `string` and not `String`, its convention to prefer the string alias

Also properties need to be public or else this won't work, period. Properties take care of encapsulation for you internally.

`public string Name { get; set; }` (capitalization is following property naming conventions). Use of properties also eliminates the need for the `getName()` method entirely

Comment: Not just convention, but also safer, since it's been known to happen for a project to have it's own "String" type, which creates ambiguity.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn good point! If anyone gets themselves into that corner, C# also has type aliases to get around that, but anyone with a `String` type they created needs to really re-think what they are doing